# Trial version login details

Tags: accurev

I just downloaded the Accurev trial version (on Window x64) and cannot get past the initial wizard. The installation said it would use postgres as the user id for the database, but I cannot figure out what user id I'm supposed to use to log in to Accurev itself.

When I run the Wizard, it tells me "No more licences available" even though I have not even set up a single user [I believe this is a 2-user trial].

Comment: Is the license server running?  Can you post up the content of the acserver.log file located under "accurev install directory/storage/site_slice/logs"?

Answer (score 2):

Almost every AccuRev operation requires licensing. The GUI needs to run commands to determine is the first-time wizard is needed and when a license is not valid/available, an error is displayed. If you run "accurev hostinfo" on the AccuRev server and compare the output to the host name in the license file the two should match. Note, the line of output that's relevant is labelled "Host name(RLM)".

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. I mistakenly assumed that the instructions saying the licence was included in the download meant that the exe would download install a *.lic file. Started from scratch and realize there were two things to download. It was smooth after that.